# Full-width dropdown vs left sidebar on mobile

Tags: website-design, mobile, menu, responsive-design

I'm in a fairly early stage of creating a responsive Wordpress theme. I have a basic fixed header bar and I'm working on a left-hand navigation panel right now. I'm taking some inspiration from the KDE Kirigami HIG.

The fixed header bar is already responsive; the name of the company disappears and the company logo becomes centered on small screens. I have a hamburger menu on the left and the navigation panel will always be shown on larger devices unless someone clicks the hamburger menu button (in the future).

[image: The desktop view of the website]

I had not yet started working on the breakpoints for the navbar on mobile when I tested it and discovered that it already looked like a menu on mobile:

[image: The mobile view of the website]

For comparison, my original mockup of the mobile menu:

[image: Mobile left-hand menu mockup]

From a usability perspective, what are the pros and cons of having a menu drop down from the top vs slide from the left? A few that come to mind:

**Pros of drop-down:**

- Apparently easier to program
- Keeps main content visible while navigating

**Cons of drop-down:**

- Inconsistent with desktop design
- No possibility of a swipe-right-to-open thing (menu button is in top-left, bad for right-handed people without swiping)
- Not as distinguished from the main content of the page

**Pros of left menu:**

- Similar to Android Material Design and KDE Kirigami design
- Common mobile website design
- Conducive to swiping

**Cons of left menu:**

- Less efficient use of vertical space

Comment: I think that the difference between these two patterns would be mainly opinion-based. As you have noticed already, both have their pros and cons. Interestingly, something that is a con can be a pro on the other hand, like this keeping content visible versus being distinguished from it. So I think there is no rationally correct answer to this question.

Comment: However, should the list of menu items be very long, I would suggest using the slideout pattern, allowing it to scroll separately from the content.

Comment: @DominikOslizlo, there are very objective reasons to prefer one option over the other, this is not opinion based at all, but a question with an answer that has been thoroughly tested

Answer (score 2):

## Use left menu (side drawer)

I will explain the reasons below each of your observations

> ## **Pros of drop-down:**
>
> **Apparently easier to program** This has nothing to do with usability, this is an implementation issue. You'll know what resources
>   you have in order to build this, but from an users perspective, this
>   is a non-issue.
>
> **Keeps main content visible while navigating** This might be true in your case, where you have only a few items. But generally speaking, if
>   you have a fair amount of items, scenario will be the same or worse:
>   left menu provides an affordance on what to do, but a menu covering
>   the whole canvas may confuse some users that accidentally touched the
>   menu button
>
> ## **Cons of drop-down:**
>
> **Inconsistent with desktop design** This is exactly the point: mobile is not the same as desktop, therefore you should provide an experience
>   built for mobile, not force a desktop clone for sake of consistency.
>   As we're at it, consistency can be achieved by the use of color,
>   fonts, imagery and such. But if you have a hamburger menu, users will
>   expect that element to act as expected, regardless of consistency
>   (which isn't true). Both options will be equally *"inconsistent"*, and
>   that's the idea
>
> **No possibility of a swipe-right-to-open thing (menu button is in top-left, bad for right-handed people without swiping)** This is a
>   very good reason not to use this version, just as you said.
>
> **Not as distinguished from the main content of the page** Exactly. This is related to what I mentioned above when you consider this as a
>   pro
>
> ## **Pros of left menu:**
>
> **Similar to Android Material Design and KDE Kirigami design** This is a huge pro!
>
> **Common mobile website design** Ditto!
>
> **Conducive to swiping** I couldn't say it better!
>
> ## **Cons of left menu:**
>
> **Less efficient use of vertical space** Quite the opposite. The idea of *[off canvas](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/offcanvas.html)* or *[sidedrawer](https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/navigation-drawer.html)* menus is to momentarily
>   interrupt the flow in order to provide focus on a task that the user
>   needs to perform (for example: choose a page to go). After that task
>   has been performed, the menu disappears, providing cues about what
>   happened and what have you done in order to get to a new location.
>   Vertical space isn't affected at all since the element is LITERALLY
>   *off canvas*

And these are just some of the reasons, based on your own observations. There are many more (for example, **crossing your thumb all the way over the screen instead of swiping to dismiss a menu!**).

## However...

If you have only 4 items, and you know they won't be more than that, I suggest you make them visible at all time and forget about hidden menus, they're [**proven to affect UX in a bad way**](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/hamburger-menus/)